# Inserting values in database manually in code in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm new in Android. So i have created the following database...

```
public class database {

    private Db DbHelper;
    private Context ct;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    private static class Db extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public Db(Context context) {
            super(context, "db", null, 1);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String query; 
            query = "CREATE TABLE currency (USD, GBP, EUR, CAD)"; 
            db.execSQL(query);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }}
    public  database(Context c){
        ct = c;
    }
}
```

Now i want to add a row of values to the table "currency" which i'll use later in my app. I want to add them in my code like:

```
INSERT INTO currency
VALUES (2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4);
```

How can i do that? Please help!

Comment: Oh come on.  At least *try* the documentation, before you ask a question!  Have a look at SQLiteDatabase.insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity, add this to `onCreate`:

```
Db db = new Db(this);
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO currency VALUES (2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4)");
```

Note that this works, but the Android documentation suggests using the [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) Command instead, since it is easier to debug if you run into problems.

Comment: This is true, but in general `execSQL` isn't really the best way to go, thus you should at least mention the *right* way to do it. i.e. `SQLiteDatabase.insert(...)`